# MicroRos subscriber callback stops getting called after receiving a couple messages

Tags: micro-ros

I am using microRos on an STM32 device which is connected to a host agent over serial. I am attempting to do a simple function first. Basically, I have the STM32 subscribing to a "heartbeat" topic. The message type (.msg file) is simply "uint8 heartbeat" The host agent publishes a "1" on this topic.

The STM32 has a callback function which I have setup. Ideally, everytime it sees a "1", an LED will toggle.

What is currently happening though, is that the LED toggles a couple times (about 11 times) before it stops toggling, even though the host agent is still publishing. The details of my STM32 implementation are below:

```
void mros_init(void *argument) {
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, LED_DEBUG_Pin);

if (rmw_uros_set_custom_transport(
true, (void*) &huart1, cubemx_transport_open, cubemx_transport_close,
        cubemx_transport_write, cubemx_transport_read) != RMW_RET_OK){
    NVIC_SystemReset();
}

//allocate freeRtos
freeRTOS_allocator = rcutils_get_zero_initialized_allocator();
freeRTOS_allocator.allocate = microros_allocate;
freeRTOS_allocator.deallocate = microros_deallocate;
freeRTOS_allocator.reallocate = microros_reallocate;
freeRTOS_allocator.zero_allocate = microros_zero_allocate;

if (!rcutils_set_default_allocator(&freeRTOS_allocator)) {
    printf("Error on default allocators (line %d)\n", __LINE__);
    NVIC_SystemReset();
}

// micro-ROS app

rcl_allocator_t allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator();

//create init_options
rcl_ret_t ret3 = rclc_support_init(&support, 0, NULL, &allocator);

if (ret3 != RCL_RET_OK) {
    NVIC_SystemReset();
}

// create node
rcl_ret_t ret0 = rclc_node_init_default(&node, "ccb", "", &support);
if (ret0 != RCL_RET_OK) {
    NVIC_SystemReset();
}
enter code here

// heartbeat subscriber
RCCHECK(rclc_subscription_init_default(
        &heartbeat_sub, &node, ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(cmr_msgs, msg, Heartbeat), "/ccb/heartbeat"));


// create timer
rcl_timer_t timer;
const unsigned int timer_rate = 100;  // 1 Hz (arbitrary value)
RCCHECK(
        rclc_timer_init_default( &timer, &support, RCL_MS_TO_NS(timer_rate), timer_callback));

// allocate message memory
bool alloc_success = alloc_msgs();
if (!alloc_success) {
    NVIC_SystemReset();
}

// create executor
rclc_executor_t executor = rclc_executor_get_zero_initialized_executor();
const size_t num_handles = 2;  // number of subscribers & timers
RCCHECK(rclc_executor_init(&executor, &support.context, num_handles, &allocator));

RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_timer(&executor, &timer));

RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_subscription(&executor, &heartbeat_sub, &heartbeat_sub_msg,
                &heartbeat_sub_callback, ON_NEW_DATA));

HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, LED_DEBUG_Pin);

rclc_executor_spin(&executor);

//ideally never gets here since executer spins forever
//NVIC_SystemReset();
dealloc_msgs();
RCCHECK(rcl_subscription_fini(&motor_sub, &node));
RCCHECK(rcl_subscription_fini(&power_sub, &node));
RCCHECK(rcl_publisher_fini(&error_pub, &node));
RCCHECK(rcl_publisher_fini(&sensor_pub, &node));
RCCHECK(rcl_subscription_fini(&heartbeat_sub, &node));
RCCHECK(rcl_node_fini(&node));

NVIC_SystemReset();
```

Above I have shown the initialization function for micro ros. You can see that I am creating the subscriber and then attaching the callback function. The callback function is simple, shown below:

```
void heartbeat_sub_callback(const void *msgin) {
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, LED_DEBUG_Pin);}
```

As you can see, I am just toggling an LED. The host agent publishes data on this topic every 5ms, so I expect that this callback should be invoked continuously. Instead, it gets invoked about 11 times and then stops. Does anyone have any clues as to what could be the problem?